# How to change object color depending on its location? (EEVEE or BI, no Cycles)

Tags: materials

I have a colored plane (4 faces 4 colors) and I'd like another plane which is above the first one to change the color accordinly depending upon which face is under.[image: Color doesn't change]

I tried Data Transfer modifier but nothing happens. What's wrong?
Or is there another way to do that? No Cycles render. EEVEE (2.8) or internal (earlier versions).
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You don't see results of modifier, because you are in solid mode. Try vertex paint mode.

Comment: Serge, it doesn't help. I don't know how to attach the picture into comment, but i switched to Vertex Paint mode, render view, just render the file - it's exactly as you see on the first picture.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you share a file?

Comment: Serge, sorry, I'm new here. What is the way to send a file? Sorry...

Comment: Upload it here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: Wow [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6748" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6748/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Your source object doesn't have vertex colors at all, hence the problem (no data to transfer)*

**To add vertex colors to an object:**

1. Add new vertex color layer
2. Go to *Vertex Paint* mode
3. Enable face selecting
4. Select face on a mesh
5. Choose a color
6. To fill a face with color: Paint -> Set Vertex Color

**Steps above in one pic:**

[image]

Now it is working in Vertex paint mode:

[image]

To see it in actual **Blender Internal** render, check *Vertex Color Paint* option in material settings:

[image]

And for **Eevee/Cycles** use *Attribute* node, just type vertex color layer name you have:

[image]

Comment: Serge, I made it and I have it work only in Texture ViewPort shading. It's grey in other modes and render as well. Is it the way it should work or something is wrong again?

Comment: So now when I checked the box in materials it WORKS! Thanks a lot!